# issue with HTTP header settings

Tags: http, header

I am trying to pull a web page in my client (not a browser) with the following settings in the HTTP header

```
Accept: "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Accept-Charset: "ISO-8859-1"
User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0"
```

however I get an error code 406, 
I also tried changing to;

```
Accept: "text/html"
```

with no success; error code and status message in the response header is

```
statusCode: 406
statusMessage: "Not Acceptable"
```

any idea waht the correct header settings should be, the page loads fine in the browser

Comment: Aren't you doing a `GET` request to the target URL? You do not even need to specify for most websites, did you try without an `Accept` header?

Comment: tried that, but I get the same 406 error status, which is why I tried setting header fields.

Comment: Can you access this URL from your browser?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out, I ran a sniffer to see which header settings worked, and here is what worked in every case

headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/523.10.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Safari/523.10',
                    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                    'Accept-language' : 'de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3'
        }

Comment: Accept headers are a tricky part of HTTP. I'm guessing the part that helped a lot was the `*;q=0.7` in the `Accept-Charset` header.  I suggest adding a similar clause to `Accept-Language` at a quality of 0.2 -- IOW, `Accept-Language: de, en;q=0.7, en-us;q=0.3, *;q=0.2`.  Without the wildcard match you run the risk of getting a 406 for a site that does not explicitly support English or German.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `Accept-Language`. See [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406)

Answer (score -1):

Why are you sending contradictory headers?  You are requesting a representation that is both UTF8 and ISO-8859-1 at the same time. I guess that you could interpret the request as being for 7-bit ASCII representation.

In this case I would omit the `Accept-Charset` and change the `Accept` header to `text/html, */*;q=0.1` so that you will get something back with a strong preference for HTML. See [the Content Negotiation section of RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3) for details about these headers.

Comment: that helped a bit, but not all. I had 13 URLs that were failing before I made the change you suggested, now I have 10 URLs that fail :-), so it did help a little bit